Thriller that ends with a family attacked on a boat by a deranged man
It's an English thriller movie, made in the US I think. I think it was made in the late 1980's or early 1990's.
Story Points:

It has a family of three: A father, a mother and teenaged daughter who are being attacked by some deranged guy (but I don't know the full reason why, since I only watched clips of it, and I was still quite young). I really don't remember much except for the final bits:
The family are on a boat by a river, and the deranged man attacks them (it happens during the night). One scene has the man forcing the mother and daughter to strip I think.
Later, the father attacks the guy, and eventually the boat crashes. The family end up on the shore, and the father and deranged man fight. Eventually the father gets the upper hand and grabs a boulder, prepared to use it to crush the guys skull
However, the guy was handcuffed to a pole attached to a piece of the boat. The river's current bring the debris and the guy back into the river before his head is crushed until he is fully submerged and drowns.
The film ends with the family embracing and a close-up to the daughters eyes and with the daughter giving a monologue of what they experienced and how the guy will haunt their nightmares or something. 

If anyone knows this movie, please inform me, thank you very much.

Martin Scorsese's Cape Fear from 1991.

Sam Bowden is a small-town corporate attorney/"Leave It to Beaver"-esque family-man. Max Cady is a tattooed, cigar-smoking, bible-quoting, rapist. What do they have in common? Fourteen years, ago Sam was a public defender assigned to Max Cady's rape trial, and he made a serious error: he hid a document from his illiterate client that could have gotten him acquitted. Now, the cagey, bibliophile Cady has been released, and he intends to teach Sam Bowden and his family a thing or two about loss.

It stars Robert De Niro, Nick Nolte, Jessica Lange and Juliette Lewis in the main roles and it ends exactly as you've described. It was a remake of a movie from the 60s. Here's the trailer:




And the 1991 CAPE FEAR was a remake of CAPE FEAR (1962) with Gregory Peck as the father and Robert Mitchum as the bad guy. The story was essentially the same.
